# Characteristics of metals compatible with semiconductor grade Ultra Pure Water (UPW)?

Tags: water, conductivity, water-treatment

I am looking to build a water conductivity sensor for semiconductor grade Ultra Pure Water (UPW). [UPW conductivity sensors](https://www.mt.com/us/en/home/products/Process-Analytics/conductivity-resistivity-analyzers/conductivity-resistivity-cell-water.html?filter%5Bmodel-family%5D=Analog&filter%5Bmodel-family%5D=UniCond) already exist, but because of price and low water volume I need to fabricate my own.

The electrode material that the commercial product link above cites is Titanium. I do not know the alloy or the surface treatment. Typically in mechanical components constructed of titanium are anodized (like aluminum) to protect the relatively reactive metal. Not sure if this is the case for these electrodes however, as thick oxide layers would greatly reduce the conductivity.

These sensors are also likely used for high volume processes and any contamination from this small area may be considered inconsequential. So even though they are "industrial grade" they may not be satisfactory for my lab application.

The [Ultrapure Water Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrapure_water#Transport) only mentions compatible plastics.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to calculate the contamination rate of polished titanium given the electrode
   areas (with assumptions of course)? With a titanium dioxide layer?
2. Are other metals that are lower on the [reactivity series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactivity_series), such as Gold or Platinum, better low-contamination electrode choices?

Comment: It is counterintuitive, but "pure" water is relatively aggressive to metals. Normally is is contained in rubber lined vessels or plastic vessels.

Comment: I understand, hence the question of how to select an electrode. Any thoughts on how to calculate the rate ions are lost for different metals?

Comment: Perhaps use an *alternating current* conductivity tester would be more suitable: see https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13363/are-there-any-diy-conductivity-sensors-that-will-hold-calibration-for-long-perio At a high frequency, the electrodes could be completely insulated by anodizing, coupled through *capacitance* to the water.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik, Thanks for the information and the DIY link! I think the problem with the alternating current solution is that the conductivity of ultrapure water is so low that the influence of ambient RF noise and metal across the room would possibly be larger than the signal itself. Might be able to improve it with some shielding but this would be a difficult route. Any thoughts on electrode selection for direct measurement?

Comment: @blacksmith37 Please stop perpetuating this myth. The reason why ultrapure water is stored in plastic containers is not because of high corrosion levels for metals. It is because even a very tiny amount of contamination by metals renders the water no longer ultrapure.

Comment: In order to replicate a commercial sensor, you are going to need to copy what they do or replicate the R&D commercial suppliers put into their sensors. That sounds like a lot of work and might cost you more than buying a sensor. Plus, creating ultrapure water is also expensive and reliant on a great deal of experience. Doing it yourself on the cheap doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: @matt_black, How can I better phrase my question to help me select an electrode material? I'm a mechanical PE, and fabricating the sensor is not a problem. Generating a small amount of ultra pure water is easily achieved by polishing with mixed bed ion exchange resin. The part missing in my understanding is electrode material selection and contamination rate for ultra pure water.  I find it unlikely that only the commercial sector understands this.  I am probably just searching the wrong vocabulary. Is there better terminology to describe this process?

Comment: Titanium grades 1 to 4 are unalloyed titanium; Grade 1 has the lowest level of impurities. However, I must agree with other comments , the lowest final total cost will be a commercial unit.

Comment: @ericnutsch I think the title already asks a better question. But I suspect that, even if you get better theoretical answers, they won't be of practical use.